# Преобразования в TextView

Tags: java, android, textview

Есть TextView, в который помещаю 3 слова. Длина 3-х слов велика, НО надо их уместить в одну строчку.
В xml'e прописал следующие параметры:

```
android:maxLines="1"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

В принципе доволен, но не совсем. К примеру если не помещается третье слово целиком, то после 2-го идёт троеточие

> Бытовая техника

и это в принципе нормально, за исключением того что первые два слова короткие. Например

> Товары и ...

Хотелось бы преобразовать к примерно следующему виду:

> Товары и усл...

Чтоб в заданный размер помещалась допустимая часть следующего слова.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашёл старый "дедовский" способ. Вместо `android:maxLines="1"` прописывать `android:singleLine`.

```
 android:ellipsize="end"
 android:singleLine="true"
```

В принципе работает как и задумывалось. Единственный минус этого приёма - is deprecated. И предлагает всё же воспользоваться `maxLines`.